# Any way to turn on/off a println in java (verbose mode)

Tags: java, debugging, println, verbose

Is there any way in Java that you can make a println appear only when requested, not by default? Basically something similar to using "-v" in many programs to give you verbose mode, with information on what is happening.

For example let's say I have an if statement in a loop, and a simple println that tells me whether the if statement evaluates to true for each iteration of the loop. Is there any other way to toggle on/off it's visibility other than commenting it out when I don't need it and uncomment it when I do? Then saving it, recompiling it, etc.

It would make it a lot easier to see what is going on in my program, but only when I want that much info. As I said, I am basically looking for a way to implement a "verbose" mode that shows print statements, without having to comment/uncomment save, recompile, etc. Does Java have anything like this?

Answer (score 6):

Your best choice is to use an appropriate logger of some kind ([log4j](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/) for example).

If that's not possible, you can "consume" the stdout and stderr using something like...

```
PrintStream nullPrintStream = new PrintStream(new OutputStream() {
    @Override
    public void write(int b) throws IOException {
    }
});
System.setErr(nullPrintStream);
System.setOut(nullPrintStream);
```

Which prevent ALL output from begin printed.  You can use a proxy process (using the current stdout wrapped in a proxy `PrintStream`) to filter the content if that's more appropriate...

Answer (score 0):

No sysout cannot be turned off using a flag. The functionality you are looking for is provided by `loggers` such as `lo4j`. Using a logger, you can use the `ConsoleAppender` and always set a log level.