# Redirecting Java Console Messages

Tags: java, debugging

I wrote a complex application and now i have to debug it with the help of some testers. The problem i'm now facing is that they cannot know what kind of exception occurred during the use of the software. Is there a fast way to get the Console stream and show it's messages in another window while the user is using an Application or an Applet?

Comment: Are you using a logging framework?

Comment: This complex application, please say you are using a real logging framework and not `System.out.println`...

Comment: Are you using the command line to run it? or is it a .jar/.exe?

Comment: Take a look at [this example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18325335/any-way-to-turn-on-off-a-println-in-java-verbose-mode/18325366#18325366) which demonstrates how to "turn off" stdout, but would be the bases for capturing the output and redirecting it to where ever you wanted.

Comment: Yes it's over 1MB of code (not that complex, but not simple). Yes, most of the times i've used priintln. Actually the test has to be started. For server side i will use a jar, for the applet it will be launched within the web page.. Thank you Mad Programmer, i'll look at this right now.

Comment: If you had used a logging framework you could have _easily_ set up a socket logger to send the log information over the wire back to base. This is one of the many reasons enterprise applications do not use `println`. In fact most IDEs will warn you of the fact that `println` is not a logging framework. I would certainly recommend a little refactoring in light of this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can redirect all console messages to file (or other stream) on application start, and then look file content for get Exception:

```
    FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream("log.txt");
    PrintStream out = new PrintStream(fos);
    System.setOut(out);
    System.setErr(out);

    System.out.println("Logged to file");
```

Answer (score 1):

Use a logging framework like [slf4j](http://www.slf4j.org/) together with [logback](http://logback.qos.ch/). It offers dozens of different "appenders" - helpers which save the log messages in various places.

For your use case, I suggest to write a new appender that collects the last 100 messages in a thread safe list.

Attach it to the root logger (see the documentation).

When an error or an exception is being logged, take all messages from the list and convert them into Strings. When using `logback`, [create an encoder](http://logback.qos.ch/manual/encoders.html) for this.

Join the strings and display them in an text editor widget so clients can easily cut&paste the message into an email.

Alternatively, you can try the existing mail appender. Configure it to respond only to errors and have it send the error directly to you. But I suggest to make sure your mail provider can handle this - we had a case where a bug in the software caused sending of over 70'000 mails over night. After that, we learned that Outlook can't handle so many mails.

Comment: I would have gone for a socket appender - send the logs down the wire to a log host. That means that you get the logging from the clients as it happens.